# Ubuntu server does not allow me to log in with the new account

Tags: command-line, login

I rencently created a new user throgh console using the following command line

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/francisco -m -G sudo francisco && sudo passwd francisco
```

The problem is when I am in the console and try to log in through it, it tries to display me the `username@hostname-$` line but before that it just bring me back to the line that asks me to enter the username.

please help

Comment: Welcome! "when I am in the console and try to log in through it", how do you do this?

Comment: through the terminal I am on tty1 and it asks me to put the username and password to log in. it is an ubuntu server OS it does not has an interface like gnome

Comment: Maybe there's an error in `/etc/passwd`? Try with the command `cat /etc/passwd | grep francisco` and post the line.